# Laravel shows error access denied for user How to fix it?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and trying to run my project but unfortunately  i am facing this error how to fix it thanks ?

please see error below

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'zubair'@'%' to database 'web_gems_mineral_cms' (SQL: 
select `value` from `ven_configurations` where `key` = mail_driver limit 1)
```

Comment: Have you configured the database credentials in .env file?

Comment: Yes  I have configured the database credentials.

Comment: What's your development stack? You should check your configuration once again. There sounds to be a very basic error in configuration,

Comment: Why is `WEB` there? It should be `DB_HOST` and so on. From where have you taken that `WEB` keyword? You should copy .env.example and use it.

Comment: Please see if your MySQL user's host is %. If that is set to localhost, this error can occur. And has enough permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

this error comes when you didnt start your xammp,wamp mysql server so please start the server and go and test phpmyadmin works or not.

inshort you did not active your mysql server so please start server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that user **zubair** doesn't have access on the database **web_gems_mineral_cms**.
Run the following command from the command line:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON web_gems_mineral_cms.* TO 'zubair'@'localhost';
```